# How can get access to children from react-native native module?

Tags: java, android, ios, react-native

I write some native module in react-native app and have code like this:

```
<MyNativeModule>
    <InnerModule />
</MyNativeModule>
```

In web react I have `props.children`. Does react-native have something like that?